# Where are Lighting Web Runtime OSS built static files?

Tags: lwc-oss, lwr, lightning-web-runtime, lwr-oss

When using LWR OSS, I'm running `npm run dev` as stated in the doc, however I don't see any built files.

When I was using `create-lwc-app` (deprecated), I could see all files generated under `dist` folder.

In LWR OSS, there is no build command in `package.json`, and I can't see any folder with the built files. Is there any build command or build folder where files would be created ?

I'm trying to deploy my LWR site to render.com, and a "Publish directory" is required. Setting it to the root folder doesn't work, whereas using `dist` folder with a site generated with `create-lwc-app` did work.

I tried to ask the question in the [Trailblazer Community](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JdShxSAF) but couldn't get the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm run dev` will only start the LWR server without any pre-built/compiled artifacts.

In this mode there is an `__lwr_cache__` directory, which will initially be empty, but will be populated with assets/modules when you load the app in your browser. This is largely intended for development purposes, but also demonstrates LWR's capability to serve pages/modules dynamically.

It sounds like with your use case, you will want to build a static site with `yarn lwr build`.  This command will read your `lwr.config.json` to pre-generate/build your app/site into `__generated_site__` directory.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I was looking for. I couldn't find an option to just build and not watch for changes, otherwise build command never terminates ?

Comment: Looks like latest lwr version doesn't watch anymore and ends correctly, thanks ! :)

Comment: Adding a comment, as this commands are now documented, this is pretty cool: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/references/cli-reference/cli-reference.html